# Order of LineStrings in MultiLineString object in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a `MultiLineString` object in which the `LineStrings` that compose it are not ordered correctly (or at least how I'd like them to be ordered).

As an example, say I have the following two LineStrings:

```
from shapely.geometry import *
LineIWant = MultiLineString([((0,0),(2,5)),((2,5),(7,10)),((7,10),(6,15))])
LineIHave = MultiLineString([((0,0),(2,5)),((7,10),(6,15)),((2,5),(7,10))])
```

As you can see, the coordinates are such that all segments connect / match up, but in the object I have, they are not in order. This is problematic when I try and use the interpolate method to get the point 75% along the object:

```
LineIHave.interpolate(.75, normalized=True)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can reorder the `LineStrings` in my `MultiLineString` object?

Comment: So,... you do not want to re-order the LineStrings within a MultiLineString, but rather re-order the points within a LineString?

Answer (score 4):

Try making the MultiLineString into a single LineString:

```
from shapely.ops import linemerge
linemerge(LineIHave)  # LINESTRING (0 0, 2 5, 7 10, 6 15)
linemerge(LineIWant)  # LINESTRING (0 0, 2 5, 7 10, 6 15)
```

And if the linemerge oriented the line the wrong way, you can reverse it:

```
LineString(linemerge(LineIWant).coords[::-1])  # LINESTRING (6 15, 7 10, 2 5, 0 0)
```